# get color on click texture three.js

Tags: colors, three.js, click, geometry, textures

(sorry for my bad english)
I'm using Three.js to create a panorama. I would like to know if it is possible to get the color of a texture which I clicked on?

For that, I already have created a sphere and I can get the 3D coordinates on the sphere where I clicked (using, raycaster, projection,...).
The texture on the sphere is a ".png" with transparency. The area I would like to detect is colored :

[image]

Could you help me?